# Retrieve title of external websites for use as link text of bare URLs

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

I have 2 URLs:

1. [Anatomy of a "Memory Leak"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104/anatomy-of-a-memory-leak)
2. http://forums.asp.net/t/1917189.aspx/1?How+to+find+single+value+in+string

the 1st one is the stack overflow URL and the 2nd one is another website URL.But when we put the stack overflow URL ,this automatically change (Anatomy of a "Memory Leak") URL to HyperLink format

**URL** :`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104/anatomy-of-a-memory-leak`

But  that **URL changed in hyperlink format like** :`Anatomy of a "Memory Leak"`

It's good ! we can manually do this ,for select text and press `ctrl+k` then past our URL.I didn't said this way. I said for add dynamic text with same functionality  (**Automatically Change the other site URL To hyperlink format same as when put stack overflow URL**) when put other website URL?

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not actually changing to a hyperlink that you're asking about - both links changed to a hyperlink. It's automatically inserting the page title into the hyperlink, as opposed to showing the destination URL for external links.

Comment: And I should clarify that even more to point out that it's not actually the page title that's displayed, but the question title.

Comment: I understand ! I just for explained like hyperlink only.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd What duplicate ? I want to automatic change url format . your link have this ?

Comment: @Rames yes in the other post it's suggested to auto retrieve the title when you put the link using the editor. (currently it's just pushing "enter link description here")

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd okay . I saw that. But there is not answer in my question .that's say for we manually do this .for select text and press ctrl+k way . i don't want that.I want add dynamically ?if you understand buddy ?

Comment: I understand,  but both requests have same purpose so the team will probably pick one, if and when they decide to do it.

Comment: your correct,But please one more time see my question buddy !!!!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  : "Automatically Change the other site URL To hyperlink format same as when put stack overflow URL "

Why the stack overflow URl was change text format?but other Url does not change the format .But we can do manually . i want to why we use the so url format functionality in when  put other website URL ????

Answer (score 1):

There are probably sites which actually does this, like Facebook would retrieve the page title and images on the page, but Facebook is a social networking site which has actual need to do this to entertain their users. Bot StackExchange sites are unlike Facebook, it is *not* a social networking site. Users post links as references, usually giving them a descriptive (or not so descriptive) text.

For example:

> You can use [`Form.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) to show the form.

Sometimes the title of links may not even be important at all. For example, links to jsfiddle/codepad/pastebin/ideone/etc... How useful will it be to show *"PHP code - 14 lines - codepad"* as the title of a link? Or *"Edit This Fiddle - jsfiddle"*?

I think this function may not be quite useful then.

Comment: if the URL is not good valid, Then We can just add the hyperlink  text  format for "This URL"  ? Is correct ?